# read excel files from sub folders in a folder in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read the excel files in subfolder from a list of folders.

```
directory_list = list()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/Sectors_Week_1/', topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        directory_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))
for root in roots:
    for i in range(len(dirs)):
        sourcepath=root+dirs[i]

        sourcefiles = os.listdir(sourcepath)
        #print(sourcefiles)   
        for j in sourcefiles:
            file_path = file_path = root+dirs[i]+ '/'+sourcefiles
            print(file_path)
           # df = pd.read_excel(file_path = root+dirs[i]+ '/'+sourcefiles[j])
```

I'm getting an error: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str.
I don't what could be the path to read the excel files.

Comment: file_path = root+str(dirs[i])+'/'+sourcefiles

Comment: That only gives the path to the sub folder, I want the path to the file in that sub folder @SubbuVidyaSekar

Comment: do u have a specific sub folder, or all the subfolders ? the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library can make this pretty easy. kindly explain more, and someone will mock up a solution for u to try out

Comment: not any specific, but every subfolders in the main folder. 
I figured: file_path = root+str(dirs[i]) + '/' + j 
It is working now, but can you tell me how to do this with pathlib library. I'm at the initial stage of learning python. @sammywemmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Thanks @sammywemmy for edits

Try module which is now in standard for paths: `pathlib`

Finding all excel files:

```py
from typing import List
import pathlib

def find_excel_files_in(directory:pathlib.Path) -> List[pathlib.Path]:
    files:List[pathlib.Path] = list()

    for filepath in directory.rglob('*.xlsx'):
        if filepath.is_file():
            files.append(filepath)

    return files

# List of your directories
directories:List[str] = ['D:/Sectors_Week_1/']

found_files:List[pathlib.Path] = list()

for directory in directories:
    directory:pathlib.Path = pathlib.Path(directory)
    found_files.extend(find_excel_files_in(directory))

for filepath in found_files:
    print(filepath)
```

Comment: damn, that worked. Thanks man! I was trying to figure this out for couple of hours. Do we really need the list of suffixes if the only suffix which my file has is .xlsx? @cl0wzed

Comment: @manish. No, you do not need all of them. Change to `suffixes = ('xlsx')`

Comment: u dont need the list of suffixes if u know exactly what u want, just ```directory.rglob('*.xlsx')``` will suffice. also rglob is recursive, so u dont need the ```'**/*``` [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob)

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy. What if there are few other folders like 'D:/Sectors_Week_1/'?