Power bi multiple excel sheets added every month
My project is to make a dashboard for finance. They make multiple excel files at the end of each month. Each excel file has multiple sheets and each sheet has multiple small tables. At the end of the month they make the same format of excel files, same table layout, same column and row names just different data obviously.
My question is if I make a dashboard for the sake of this question lets say I make bar charts and I only have a folder for first month January at the start of this project that will be simple because I am working with data just from January month.
Now when it gets to February now the data source will have 2 folders of multiple excel sheets from different months but with same table column names and rows but just different data because its a new month.
I want the data to be compared with in the graphs so i can show both data together so the different is visable.
what is the process and how do i make powerbi pick up the new months of data (i cant make a master excel sheet because i will have to update it and it will keep growing bigger and bigger - i want to be just able to add the new months folder of excel files and want powerbi to pick up this is new month and add this into the graphs to compare with previous month) . rather than every month going into power bi and having a master sheet and adding new tables for each and making the data add up ? is there a way to automate this?

I would make a python script using the pandas library. You can have it compile all the excel files into one dataframe everytime you hit refresh query in powerbi.

@Matt0706 do you have any example of this please ? and where and how do I structure the excel files? do i place them into a folder with the python script also present?

You should be able to create a list of all the excel file locations with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226942/read-excel-files-from-sub-folders-in-a-folder-in-python
And then read/combine them with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat
The location of the python script won't matter if you specify what folder it should look in. In powerbi when you select the script as an import, you should see "df" as the combined table.

@Matt0706 ok will look into this but still unclear will get back you once i start this implementation

Why Python? You can import a table of all files in a folder using Folder.Files, filter out any you don't need (e.g. non-Excel files), add columns to the table of the processing results, then combine them all into one big flat file. If this would work for you, let me know and I'll write up an answer.

@JSmart523 but every month new files would be added. so does that mean every month i would have to do the clean up ? or automatically it would be added into one big file?

If you specify a parent folder that contains all monthly folders, it should work. Folder.Files is recursive into subdirectories.
